# Yii2 создание произвольного количества динамически наполняемых выпадающих списков

Tags: php, yii2

нужен совет... Наверное даже разъяснение...
Руководствовался этой статьей https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/input-tabular-input

При таком представлении _form:

```
foreach ($tableFromTemplate as $index => $setting) {
    echo $form->field($setting, '[$index]id_table')->dropDownList(
    ArrayHelper::map($tableDesc, 'id', 'tag_table_desc')
)->label(false);
```

у меня создаются корректно наполненные выпадающие списки, но при построении dom ключ передается как [$index]... Соответственно я не могу сохранить измененные данные... Не могу понять ведь я передаю в значение формы значение ключа...

А в таком виде, foreach без реализации выпадающего списка через dropDownList, все работает, все сохраняется, ключ [$index]принимает значения и в dom передается в виде [0],[1](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/input-tabular-input)...

```
foreach ($tableFromTemplate as $index => $setting) {
      echo $form->field($setting, "[$index]id_table")->label($setting->id_table);}
```

Контроллер

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    $tableDesc =TagTable::find()->asArray()->all();//для массива имен таблиц

    $idTemplate = $model->id;

    $tableFromTemplate = TableFromTemplate::find()->where(['id_template' => $idTemplate])->indexBy('id')->all();//массив моделей для редактируемого шаблона

    if (Model::loadMultiple($tableFromTemplate, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($tableFromTemplate)) {
        foreach ($tableFromTemplate as $setting) {
            $setting->save(false);
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'category' => TemplateCategory::find()->all(),
            'tableDesc' => $tableDesc,
            'tableFromTemplate' => $tableFromTemplate
        ]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Глупая ошибка... Одинарные кавычки...  `'[$index]id_table'`